# How to avoid Internet Explorer pausing while Ajax GET completes

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a situation where I'm trying to load JSON data into a popup using AngularJS and Bootstrap. It loads fine in Chrome, Edge, and other browsers I've tested: the popup appears, then there is a spinner that shows until the content loads. But in Internet Explorer, when I click to load the popup, it appears that all scripts on the page pause until all of the data is received. For several seconds, nothing appears to be happening; then, the popup shows up with the requested content. We are using classic ASP to serve the data.

I have tried setting a timeout and now the popup will show up, but once the call starts, the spinner freezes until the data shows up.

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this and knows of a workaround? This is the simplified version of what I have so far:

```
    $scope.loadData = function() {
        if (!isLoaded) {
            $scope.loading = true;
            $timeout(function(){
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/get_data.asp'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    $scope.data = res.data.data;
                    $scope.loading = false;
                });
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check your code. Does it really set `$scope.loading=true` in the `.then` block?

Comment: Oops, it should be false! It is correct in the code. Will correct that now.